# Differentiation problem involving chain and product rules: $y=(3x+2)^2 e^{5x} + \sin (3x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am just stuck on 2 questions. I have managed to complete one however I keep finding various answers to it using online calculators so I'm not sure if it's correct. The other I'm stuck on.
I could really appreciate your help:

Find $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$  for each of the following:

Q1.   $$y=(3x+2)^2 \cdot e^{5x} + \sin (3x)$$
A1:   let $(3x+2)$ be $u$

Using Chain Rule:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}u} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x}$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}u} = [2(u)^1] \cdot [3]$$
$$= 2\cdot(3x+2)\cdot3 = 6\cdot(3x+2) = (18x + 12)$$

Second part: $e^{5x}$

Again using chain rule: let $5x$ be $u$
$$y=e^u$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=[e^{5x}] \cdot [5]$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=5\cdot e^{5x}$$

Third Part: $\sin (3x)$

Chain Rule: let $(3x)$ be $u$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=[\cos (u)] \cdot [3]$$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = 3 \cos (3x)$$

Final Answer: $(18x + 12)\cdot5\cdot e^{5x} + 3\cos(3x)$

Simplified: $= (90x + 60) \cdot e^{5x} + 3\cos(3x).$

I keep finding different answers using the online differentiation calculators so I'm worried it could be wrong. Could you please advise?

In second question, I've managed to complete half (I do not know if it is correct) and am stuck on the second part.

Q2.  Find $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$  for each of the following:
$\tan^2(2x=1) + 2^{2x-1}$

Using chain rule:

part $1$ .    $[\tan (2x+1)]^2$
let $[\tan (2x+1)]$ be $u$:
$$2.[\tan (2x+1)]$$

part $2$ let $(2x+1)$ be $u$
$=[\sec^2(2x+1)\cdot(2)]$

Simplified  = $4\tan (2x+1)\sec^2.(2x+1)$

Is this correct so far?
and how do I go about to do the third part to find the derivative of $2^{2x-1}$?

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please read this http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference 

I don't mean to be rude but this was quite painful to read. In the future, please try to make it clear what you are saying are equal (like $a=b$, not just $=b$ without having said $a$). At the start of question $2$, you have an $=$ sign. Do you mean $-$? Also having $=$ signs nested in an equation is quite confusing. e.g. $a=(b=1)\cdot(c=2)$. Thanks for reading.

Comment: I apologise for any inconvenience, I didn't know you can do that.

Comment: It's cool. I'm just trying to increase clarity so people can better answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

- For Q1, note that you forgot to use Product Rule:
  $$
  \frac{d}{dx} \left[(3x + 2)^2e^{5x}\right] = \left[\frac{d}{dx}(3x + 2)^2\right]e^{5x} + (3x + 2)^2\left[\frac{d}{dx}e^{5x}\right]
  $$
- For Q2, note that:
  $$
  \frac{d}{du} \left[ b^u \right] = b^u\ln b
  $$

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I think my brain's shut off at this time :(

Comment: So for question one;
$$y= u.v$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = u\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}u} \cdot v\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x}$$

therefor:  $$[(3x + 2)^2] . [5.e^(5x)] + [e^5x] . [18x + 12]$$
what next?! I'm sorry I'm lost.

as for the second question, would the final correct answer be:
$$ 4.tan(2x + 1) . sec 2 .(2x + 1) + 2^(2x - 1) + ln 2 $$?
Sorry to take up your time... I hope it looks better now =>

Comment: Yes, applying Product Rule should give something like:
$$
(3x + 2)^2 \cdot [e^{5x} \cdot 5] + e^{5x} \cdot [2(3x + 2) \cdot 3]
= 5(3x + 2)^2e^{5x} + 6(3x + 2)e^{5x}
$$
As for the second question, you would need to apply Chain Rule in order to get something like:
$$
4\tan(2x + 1)\sec^2(2x + 1) + (2^{2x - 1}\ln 2) \cdot 2
$$